# Why Doesn't Knockout Validation Required Work Initially?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Check out the following fiddle using knockoutjs and knockout-validation on a simple form. Why doesn't the validation message appear if you click "go" initially?

Javascript:

```
var viewmodel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(null).extend({
        required: true
    });
    self.validation = ko.validatedObservable({
        name: self.name
    });
    self.go = function() {
        console.log(self.name());
        self.name.isValid();
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
<button type="button" data-bind="click:go">
  go
</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malbert69/mzmqdwmf/)

Comment: What do you mean by "initially"? The subsequent clicks no validation message appears either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that there is currently nothing that will trigger the validator to run.

The KO validator plugin by default is triggered on change of a value. On initial load, the value of your input is null, and the click event thats defined wont change this value, forcing the validator to trigger.

Instead, in your go click event, try calling showAllMessages if something is invalid:

```
var viewmodel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(null).extend({
    required: true
  });
  self.validation = ko.validation.group([self.name]);

  self.go = function() {
    if(self.name.isValid()){
        console.log("I'm valid!");
        console.log("Name: " + self.name());
    }else{
        self.validation.showAllMessages();
    }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thqb45sq/)